# mySQL Workbench Error: Syntax Error, unexpected single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I was trying to make a SQL statement in PHP, to convert a string into a time(6). But I have tried everything, for the last 12 hours, and have not made an inch of progress. I have tried these statements, all yield the same error.

```
UPDATE scheduling SET start='03:42PM' WHERE activityid=2;

UPDATE scheduling SET start=CONVERT(TIME(6),'03:42PM');

INSERT INTO scheduling(start) VALUES (start=CONVERT(TIME(6),'03:42PM')); 

INSERT INTO scheduling(start) VALUES (start=CONVERT(TIME(6),'03:42PM'));

INSERT INTO scheduling(start) VALUES (start=CONVERT(TIME(6),'15:42'));
```

The error is

> Syntax Error: unexpected '03:42PM'(single quoted text)"

I do not know how to fix this, the table exists, and i have sucesfully got other info using statements like `SELECT activityid=2 FROM xxxxxx.scheudling`

I guess I have two questions, either answer would work.

1. In my PHP document, how would I convert a string I get in from an Android Studio volley to a date. (I get the variable correctly, with `$start=$_Post("start")`, so that works, but I cant convert it into a time. I looked online, and tried everything that looked like it work work.
2. Conversion through SQL Code, I already tried `CAST` and `CONVERT`, neither works. My start column is type `TIME(6)`.

Comment: Sorry Im still a bit new to SO, thanks John....

Comment: noted I will modify my above question thanks

Comment: `TIME` does no accept `PM`, you would have to convert it to a 24 hour format

Comment: In that case, then this should work "INSERT INTO scheduling(start) VALUES (start=CONVERT(TIME(6),'15:42'));" but it doesn't...I will add it to the list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend testing expressions using a SELECT statement.

Firstly, the MySQL `CONVERT` function arguments are flipped around backwards.

The syntax is `CONVERT(expr,type)`

And `type` is supplied as a keyword, not a string literal. For example:

```
 SELECT CONVERT('235',SIGNED)
```

To convert to a `TIME` datatype

```
 SELECT CONVERT( '15:42' ,TIME(6))     // => 15:42:00.000000
```

The 'PM' part of the string literal will be ignored.

```
 SELECT CONVERT( '03:42PM' ,TIME(6))   // => 03:42:00.000000
```

We can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to return a TIME value from a string that contains the AM/PM indicator

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '03:42PM' ,'%h:%i%p')
```

And there's no need to cast that to `TIME(6)`, we can do this:

```
UPDATE scheduling
  SET start = STR_TO_DATE( '03:42PM' ,'%h:%i%p') 
WHERE activityid = 2
```

---

The `STR_TO_DATE` function is documented here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

The format patterns for `STR_TO_DATE` are documented here, under `DATE_FORMAT`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Demonstration:

setup

```
USE test;
CREATE TABLE scheduling (activityid INT PRIMARY KEY, start TIME(6));
-- 0 row(s) affected
INSERT INTO scheduling (activityid) VALUES (2);
-- 1 row(s) affected
```

execute the update statement in the answer above

```
UPDATE scheduling SET start = STR_TO_DATE( '03:42PM' ,'%h:%i%p') WHERE activityid = 2 ;
-- 1 row(s) affected
```

results

```
SELECT * FROM scheduling WHERE activityid = 2;
-- activityid  start
-- ----------  ---------------
--          2  15:42:00.000000
```

---

**SECOND FOLLOWUP**

Use same `sql_mode` setting reported by OP:

```
SET @@sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' ;
```

Test:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '03:42PM' ,'%h:%i%p')
```

returns

```
(NULL)
```

But this more complicated expression:

```
SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(),' ', '03:42PM' ),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
```

returns

```
15:42:00
```

The more complicated expression is a workaround to avoid behavior imposed by the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` in the `sql_mode`.